# How to detect if CLOSED ionic app was launched from a local notification

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, localnotification

I'm using ionic 5 and cordova with the [local-notification-plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/local-notifications) to create reminders for an ios and android app.

When the user clicks on the local notification, the click event handler will check the clicked notification and navigate the user to a specific page.

```js
// app.cmp
this.localNotifications.on('click').subscribe((res) => {...});
```

This works fine **only** if the app is in active or in the background. If the app is closed, the subscription returns nothing after the app is launched.

Is there a reliable way I can detect that the app has been opened by a local notification?
I need this to work for android and ios using the ionic and cordova.

Furthermore, the plugin states that there is a [launchDetails](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications#launch-details) property, which seems not to be working.

Comment: Seems like there's an open issue for this already: https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/issues/1836